ReactDom.render no more supported on React 18, use createRoot
I have this warrning, === ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17 ===
my app is working on MFE, micro frontends,
this is how my root.ts file
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import singleSpaReact from "single-spa-react";
import { ErrorBoundary } from "Components/ErrorBoundary";
import { Root } from "./root.component";

const domElementGetter = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("main");
  if (!el) {
    el = document.createElement("div");
    el.id = "main";
    el.className = "main";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
  return el;
};

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  domElementGetter,
  errorBoundary: () => <ErrorBoundary />,
  rootComponent: Root,
});

export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;````


do you know how to properly configure, the new React 18 with react-spa-react to get rid of this warning? 


Did you try using ReactDOMClient instead of ReactDOM as shown in the docs (https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-react/)?

yes, but it did not worked

are you using the latest version of single-spa-react?
